# List validation Sharepoint 2010: How do I validate date column based on Status?

Tags: list, validation

I have an Action Items list that captures [Created], [Status], and [Date Completed] columns. [Date Completed] is an optional column to be entered at a later date when the Action Item is closed. If [status]="Completed", [Date Completed] must be greater than or equal to [Created]. If [status]=blank, no validation is needed and [Date Completed] can be left blank. How do I code this formula? I have tried to adapt several similar formulas posted on this site without success. In all cases, SharePoint displays an error that [Date Completed] must be > Created no matter what value is selected in [Status].

Comment: It almost sounds like you would be better off using a workflow than trying to mess with validated columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use list validation for this. Make the column [Date Completed] a non required field. Then go to

List Settings -> Validation settings

Try this:

> =OR(AND([Status]="Completed", [Date Completed]>=[Created]), [Status]="None")

Make your message something about how Date completed needs to be filled in if the item is completed.

Comment: Just a not on this. The formula could be simplified as:
=OR([Status]<>"Completed", [Date Completed]>=[Created])